# Database update time with increment based on number of records SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am using SQL Server and there's a mistake in the data that I want to fix.

I want to fix these data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [JBINFOTECH].[dbo].[leads]
WHERE calldate = '1970-01-01 01:00:00.000' ORDER BY id DESC;
```

So basically those leads that are in date time `1970-01-01 01:00:00.000` there are 756 of them.

What I want to do is to run a query something like:

```
UPDATE [JBINFOTECH].[dbo].[leads]
SET calldate = '2016-01-28 09:12:00.000'
WHERE calldate = '1970-01-01 01:00:00.000';
```

Basically I just want to update those `1970's` date time. But is it possible to update each of 756 records with increments in minutes? Let's say

```
SET calldate = '2016-01-28 09:12:00.000'
```

So that is the start and for ever record there will be 5 minutes increment in the time so basically the next record that I will update will become

```
SET calldate = '2016-01-28 09:17:00.000'.
```

Because it can't be all the same value there should be difference in time. Is it possible in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) and [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(ROW_NUMBER_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) - 1 RN
  FROM [JBINFOTECH].[dbo].[leads]
  WHERE calldate = '1970-01-01 01:00:00.000'
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET
  CALLDATE = DATEADD(MINUTE, RN * 5, '2016-01-28 09:12:00.000')
```

Comment: here you are updating CTE, not original table.

Comment: This works for me perfectly and much simplier. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you can insert id's for 756 rows with generated row numbers in a temparory table

then loop through the temp table and update your original table.

```
declare @newcalldate as datetime 
SET @newcalldate = '2016-01-28 09:12:00.000'

/*loop start*/
set @tempid= ---   //get id from current row.

 UPDATE [JBINFOTECH].[dbo].[leads]
 SET calldate = newcalldate 
 WHERE id=@tempid and calldate = '1970-01-01 01:00:00.000';

 set @newcalldate=dateadd(mi,5,@newcalldate)

/* lood ends*/
```

Comment: You are refering to a temporary table, you are not populating that table, you are not even creating that table, your loop does not exists. Looping through a table for this purpose is not the correct approach. Your code will update the table with the same value for all rows.

Comment: NO. in where clause i am using one more condition: id=tempid, where tempid means ,id of current row in #temp table.

Comment: That makes your answer even more incorrect. You are joining a table in that isn't there.

Comment: /* loop start*/ and /* loop ends*/ should be replaced with proper code like while loop. and you can include row number while inserting id's in temp tabel , so that you can use looping.